# Binding to ViewModel on ListView shows nothing but works fine on other controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to bind an ObservableCollection sitting in my ViewModel class to a ListView that uses a GridView for displaying rows but I am unable to show my data in the list.

For testing purposes I put a TextBlock and can successfully show the data with Binding (however only if I do `DataContext = ViewModel` in code behind first, doing `ViewModel.MyData` in XAML does not work)

I've noticed that whatever `ItemsSource` is bound to, there is always a random number of empty element showing in the list, I can tell that since when I hover my mouse on the ListView the rows highlight. This number does not match the capacity of my collection.

If in code behind I manually set the `ItemsSource` to the collection I want to display, the correct number of element then shows up but there are still no data displayed.

**XAML**

```
<Page x:Class="GestionStockWPF.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GestionStockWPF"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="MainPage"
      ShowsNavigationUI="False">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="13*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="77*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- The Binding here seems to do nothing, there isn't the correct amount of rows in the app -->

        <ListView x:Name="listView"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Grid.Row="1" Margin="30, 0, 30, 30" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Tests}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=A}"
                        Header="Asset Number" Width="200"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <!-- This textblock is just here for testing purposes, it successfully shows "A" -->

        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Tests[0].A}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="252,28,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Code Behind File**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace GestionStockWPF
{
    public partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPageViewModel ViewModel;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();

            // If I do DataContext = this;
            // and then set the binding of the TextBlock to "ViewModel.Tests[0].A" nothing is shown
            DataContext = ViewModel;

            // If I don't do that the listview does not contain the correct number of rows
            listView.ItemsSource = ViewModel.tests;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel & Test class**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace GestionStockWPF
{
    // Not sure if I have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged but my real class does it
    public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string A { get { return "A"; } }
        public string B { get { return "B"; } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    public class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
            {
                Tests.Add(new Test());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `DataContext = this` doesn't work because bindings require property and `ViewModel` is a field.

Answer (score 1):

Your binding is incorrect.

It should be:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding tests}"
```

You need to specify the path in the binding, not the binding source.

The explicit `Path` part is optional in a binding, so you also can change your text block binding to:

```
Text="{Binding tests[0].A}"
```

By the way, the properties should use `PascalCase`, so better call it `Tests`.

Comment: Removing `Source=` from `ItemsSource` seems to fix the issue where the incorrect number of rows where displayed, which makes me think `Tests` is now properly bound to the list view but there is still no content in it. I also edited my original post so `tests` become `Tests`

Comment: why even when i set `DataContext = this`; in my *MainWindow.xaml.cs* , it shows the data i binded normally only when its bind to a *<listview>* , but when its bind to individual elements <TextBox> or <TextBlock> .. etc its not working unless i set it to something like `DataContext = Product` or {Binding Product[0].name <== ugly thing }? is there is a possibility to make it work without doing DataContext = Product ??? cause this has disabled some callbacks im bringing from my mainwindow  ......